# Why does setting resizable to false cause some padding to appear?

Tags: java, swing

Here is the simple program to understand the way `JFrame::setResizable(boolean)` works:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0);

//Adding buttons
p1.setLayout(fl);
p1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
p1.add(new JButton("1"));
p1.add(new JButton("1"));
p1.add(new JButton("1"));
p1.add(new JButton("1"));
p1.add(new JButton("1"));

//Adding to JFrame
frame.add(p1);
frame.pack();

//Here is where the problem comes
frame.setResizable(false);

//The rest...
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

And this is what it shows:

[image]

Now when I change `frame.setResizable(false);` to `frame.setResizable(true);` it works as follows (I didn't do any resizings, it's just after the startup) :

[image]

***QUESTION:*** Where does the padding in the first example come from? How to make the `resizable = false` window as in the second example (i.e. without these paddings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks from this [discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1351952?start=0&tstart=0), that the problem won't occur anymore if you change the order of `setResizable`and `pack` (I tested this and it worked).

So call them in this order :

1)

```
frame.setResizable(false);
```

2)

```
frame.pack();
```

Comment: Cool, thanks much!